# assigning ggplot grob to variables with having all values resolve at time of assignment

Tags: r, ggplot2

What is the correct way to assign a ggplot2 grob to a variable if the object includes other variabels that I would like to be resolved at the time of assigning.

For example:
  `xpos` and `ypos` are values that I would like resolved. 
  I am assigning geom_text to ptext, which I then want to add to some plots, say p1 and p2.

```
xpos <- .2
ypos <- .7

ptext <- geom_text(aes(x = xpos, y = ypos, label = "Some Text"))
```

I can add ptext to another plot and everything works as expected

```
## adding ptext to a plot
p1 <- qplot(rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
p1 + ptext
```

**However, removing (or altering) `xpos` & `ypos` gives undesired results.**

```
rm(xpos, ypos)

p2 <- qplot(rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
p2 + ptext
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'xpos' not found
```

What is the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put `xpos` and `ypos` in a data frame. In your example:

```
coords = data.frame(xpos=.2, ypos=.7)

ptext <- geom_text(data=coords, aes(x = xpos, y = ypos, label = "Some Text"))

## adding ptext to a plot
p1 <- qplot(rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
p1 + ptext   

# removing (or altering) the old coords data frame doesn't change the plot,
# because it was passed by value to geom_text
rm(coords)

p2 <- qplot(rnorm(5), rnorm(5))
p2 + ptext
```